# ACE editor get selected word after double click

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

When I double-click on a word, I would like to get that word.

```
    editor = ace.edit("code_editor");
    editor.on('dblclick', function() {
        var selected_word = editor.getSelectedText()
    });
```

I can detect double-click with the code above. However, selected word is always empty. It is too fast, and does not allow a complete word to get selected. What is the solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption was right it was too fast. I've tried to delay the selection grab and it worked fine using this:

```
editor.on("dblclick", function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        var selected_word = editor.getSelectedText();
        console.log(selected_word);
    }, 10);
});
```

**And that solved the issue**

```js
      var editor = ace.edit("editor");
      editor.on("dblclick", function () {
        setTimeout(() => {
          var selected_word = editor.getSelectedText();
          console.log(selected_word);
        }, 10);
      });
```

```css
      #editor {
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Ace Editor</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium
      expedita porro doloremque error, nobis dignissimos ducimus quidem. Quo
      cumque pariatur debitis laborum, minus magnam enim, repudiandae omnis iste
      cupiditate culpa.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Added working code snipet